# Ningx non-www to www redirect causing site to show as "not available"/"server not found"

Tags: redirect, nginx

Running LEMP stack: nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

I've tried a number of different configurations to get my non-www domain to prepend *www.* onto all URLs and despite double checking the following configuration against many others I continue to get errors ("not available"/"server not found"). Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a 301 redirect and not 302.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/laravel/mysite/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name mysite.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com$request_uri;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I define *server_name* then I define the rewrite directly below it. This has worked in the past but not working now. I remove the "return" line and the domain without *www.* works perfectly. There are no other configurations running. Can someone tell me if this configuration contains an error or if I'm attempting to do this incorrectly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate it into 2 server blocks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com;

    return 301 $scheme://www.site.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name www.site.com;

    root /var/www;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
...
```